# When should I activate the "launch folder windows in a separate process" option?

Tags: performance, windows-explorer

In folder options -> view, there's an option that's off by default called "Launch folder windows in a separate process". I'm on windows-7, but I know this capability has existed since at least windows xp.

When is it advantageous to do this? When does this option improve performance? Are there any other considerations to take into account before using this option?

Comment: See http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/run-windows-explorer-folders-in-a-separate-process-to-prevent-crashes-and-system-freeze/ which summarizes: "So why is this option not enabled by default? Because it has many side effects and should not be used on systems with less than 4GB RAM (since it takes slightly more memory). Also it can confuse Explorer extensions when they find there are more than one instance of them running."

Answer (score 13):

the main reason i would suggest turning this on is so that if you have a folder window open which stops responding and you kill the task, it won't/shouldn't take the main explorer.exe with it (meaning your desktop won't be inaccessible for a few moments while windows restarts it).

I am unsure what advantage there would be to not having it enabled other than not using as much memory.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a pretty old post, but I ran into it during a search so figured others might as well.

One other reason to do this is to allow running Explorer.EXE as a different user than the one currently logged in. Be aware though, this has the potential to use more resources on your system.

[Check this blog post for more detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/aaron_margosis/runas-with-explorer).

Comment: That link is dead now. There is an archived copy at Web Archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150308043237/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2004/07/07/175488.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

One difference between opening folders in a separate process or not has to do with how the copy, move, delete, rename file transfer dialog boxes are presented.  From what I've read from Windows Insiders, when folders open in a separate process the transfer dialogs all appear beneath (UNDER) all other open windows — even alerts that require your immediate attention (as in file conflicts).  Apparently leaving "Launch windows folders in a separate process" at its default setting with the  option UNchecked, the file transfer dialogs appear as you would expect them to:  ON TOP of all other open windows.  To me this decides it: I'm leaving it unchecked.

Comment: I've just tested this on Windows 10 with the option both ticked and unticked. I generated a few file transfer and rename conflict dialogs in both situations, with multiple explorer windows open to the same folder, and found that the dialogs/warnings behaved the same in both modes in terms of appearing over/under open windows.  Also, I have quite a few file explorer extensions installed and will monitor them in the coming days with this option ticked.

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows 10 Build 1903 this option is enabled by default.

*It is not known why this setting was not previously enabled by default, other than that it may cause an increase in memory and CPU utilization due to the use of additional processes. With the greater system requirements of PCs running Windows 10, Microsoft may have decided that computers are powerful enough to not feel the effects of the additional processes.*

- [Source](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-build-1903-opens-folders-in-their-own-process-by-default/)

Comment: I have Windows 10 20H2 and the option is **not** enabled. Maybe it is enabled on a fresh installation? My PC updated from an older build.

Comment: Did a fresh installation of Windows 11 recently and it was not enabled either.  If it was default in version 1903 it might have been rolled back due to feedback and/or telemetry indicating issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think its best to to launch each in its own process so that if one locks up it doesn't take the main explorer.exe down with it. I would only deselect this option if you are really low on Ram, as running all off one process should use less.